# Trying to find the frequency of words in a file using a script

Tags: bash, scripting

The file I have is called `test` and it contains the following lines:

```
This is a test Test test test There are multiple tests.
```

I want the output to be:

```
test@3 tests@1 multiple@1 is@1 are@1 a@1 This@1 There@1 Test@1
```

I have the following script:

```
 cat $1 | tr ' ' '\n' > temp # put all words to a new line
    echo -n > file2.txt # clear file2.txt
    for line in $(cat temp)  # trace each line from temp file
    do
    # check if the current line is visited
     grep -q $line file2.txt 
     if [ $line==$temp] 
     then
    count= expr `$count + 1` #count the number of words
     echo $line"@"$count >> file2.txt # add word and frequency to file
     fi
    done
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `sort | uniq -c | sort -n` to create a frequency table. Some more tweaking needed to get the desired format.

```
 tr ' ' '\n' < "$1" \
 | sort \
 | uniq -c \
 | sort -rn \
 | awk '{print $2"@"$1}' \
 | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: For the assignment I have to use this format, of a for loop and if,

Answer (score 3):

**`grep`** + **`sort`** + **`uniq`** + **`sed`** pipeline:

```
grep -o '[[:alnum:]]*' file | sort | uniq -c | sed -E 's/[[:space:]]*([0-9]+) (.+)/\2@\1/'
```

The output:

```
a@1
are@1
is@1
multiple@1
test@3
Test@1
tests@1
There@1
This@1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat >wdbag.py
#!/usr/bin/python

from collections import *
import re, sys

text=' '.join(sys.argv[1:])       

t=Counter(re.findall(r"[\w']+", text.lower()))

for item in t:
  print item+"@"+str(t[item])

$ chmod 755 wdbag.py 

$ ./wdbag.py "This is a test Test test test There are multiple tests."
a@1
tests@1
multiple@1
this@1
is@1
there@1
are@1
test@4

$ ./wdbag.py This is a test Test test test There are multiple tests.
a@1
tests@1
multiple@1
this@1
is@1
there@1
are@1
test@4
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11300418/3720510

Comment: add a `,` last on the print -line to get the list one a single row.

Comment: why are you using lower() when the desired output is differentiated according to case?

Comment: Because I'm not a Practically Perfect Person: If you look behind the Ref: -link you see that the code is a perfect copy of what you find there. Now: You might consider `.lower()` to be an option that is easy to remove, but harder to add - if you do not know about it. Therefore the answer 'covers more ground' than without it.

Comment: FWIW: `python3` on the first line, and `print( item+"@"+str(t[item]) )` as replacement (added parentheses) is what is required to have this work with py3. Optionally `, end=''` inside the last `)` for print - to have the items listen on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` only:

```
 awk -v RS='( |\\.|\n)' '{s[$0]++} 
     END{for (x in s) {printf "%s%s", SEP,x"@"s[x]; SEP=" "}; print ""}' infile
```

This defines the **R**ecord **S**eparator either a *space*, *dot* or *`\n`ewline*, then save fields into an array called `s` with the key as whole fields/words and for each seen of the words, increment the occurrences in array that represents the value of the keys in array.

At the `END` loop over the elements of the array and first print the keys (fields/words) `x`, a `@` and their value as occurrences `s[x]`.

The **SEP** as a variable used to add spaces between each words when printing and on second to the next words.

Answer (score 0):

Using grep and awk..

```
 grep -o '[[:alnum:]]*' file | awk '{ count[$0]++; next}END {ORS=" "; for (x in count)print x"@"count[x];print "\n"}'
```

tests@1 Test@1 multiple@1 a@1 This@1 There@1 are@1 test@3 is@1

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk '
{
    for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        arr[$i]++
    }
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"

    for(i in arr) {
        printf "%s@%s ", i, arr[i]
    }
    print ""
}
' FPAT='[a-zA-Z]+' input.txt
```

**Explanation**

`PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"` - Order by element values in descending order (rather than by indices). Scalar values are compared as numbers. See [Predefined Array Scanning Orders](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html).

`FPAT='[a-zA-Z]+'` - A regular expression describing the contents of the fields in a record.  When set, `gawk`
                   parses the input into fields, where the fields match the regular expression, instead of
                   using the value of the FS variable as the field separator.

**Input**

```
This is a test Test test test There are multiple tests.
This is a test Test test test There are multiple tests.
This is a test Test test test There are multiple tests.
```

**Output**

```
test@9 tests@3 Test@3 multiple@3 a@3 This@3 There@3 are@3 is@3
```

Comment: Could you use the code I already posted, Im restricted to that format,

Comment: @SamuraiBale No, because of this - [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/109397). You use the inappropriate approach to solving your task. It is like coding game in the `bash` - it can be done (for example "tetris" in the terminal window), but the `bash` is the not right instrument for this. The same for text processing - the `awk` is the right tool for this, the `bash` loop is not.

Answer (score 0):

As OP asked in the same kind of format...

```
bash-4.1$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

tr ' ' '\n' < ${1} > temp
while read line
do
    count=$(grep -cw ${line} temp)
    echo -n "${line}@${count} "
done < temp
echo ""

bash-4.1$ bash test.sh test.txt
This@1 is@1 a@1 test@3 Test@1 test@3 test@3 There@1 are@1 multiple@1 tests.@1

bash-4.1$ cat test.txt
This is a test Test test test There are multiple tests.
```